# How do I extract dates from a weekly tracker?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table, date, tracking

Let's say in each hour of the day in a week I record for example the food I eat or the physical activity I do.

At the end of the week, I have a table where the rows are hours (12am-12:59am to 11pm-11:59pm) and the columns are days (Sunday until Saturday) and the values are the foods that I have eaten.

How do I get a list of the dates that I have eaten certain foods? For example I have eaten banana 10am-11am Mondays and Thursdays except the Monday of the third week of the month. I instead ate banana on Tuesday of that week.

How do I get the dates?

I have tried using countif, index, match, but I believe I am missing a very simple solution involving pivot tables or looking for the right template. If worst comes to worst, I am willing to (re)learn VBAs/macros, but I highly doubt that there is no template out there or pivot table solution to this.

---

Parts of my food consumption tracker

[image]

---

I want to end up with something like (Table 3):

---

[image]

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 1):

With the way your data is formatted, you would need to search through the sheet for each instance of Banana, and then use the row and column numbers to refer back to the date and time at which this was eaten, this could be done in VBA. One of the problems with your current format, is that you want to search for banana, but sometimes it is mixed in cells with eggs, sometimes carrot, and sometimes by it self.

However, it would seem that your data could be arranged in a more computer friendly but less user friendly way. You really have a series of time stamps, with a single food after each one, this could be in a column series like below, and with additional columns for calculations

```
Date    Food    Hour    Day Week
30/01/2017 10:00    sandwich    10  2   5
30/01/2017 10:00    apple   10  2   5
30/01/2017 10:00    pancake 10  2   5
30/01/2017 16:00    eggs    16  2   5
30/01/2017 16:00    hotdog  16  2   5
31/01/2017 16:00    carrot  16  3   5
31/01/2017 16:00    eggs    16  3   5
31/01/2017 16:00    chips   16  3   5
02/02/2017 16:00    eggs    16  5   5
02/02/2017 17:00    banana  17  5   5
03/02/2017 18:00    orange  18  6   5
04/02/2017 12:00    ham 12  7   5
```

Once you have the data like this, you can list your food types across the page

```
sandwich    apple   pancake eggs    hotdog  carrot  banana  ham
   1       2         3       4      5      6        10      12
#N/A      #N/A     #N/A      7     #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
#N/A      #N/A     #N/A      9     #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
#N/A      #N/A     #N/A      #N/A   #N/A    #N/A    #N/A    #N/A
```

Finding the first occurrence is easy - just use match(), but then the next time you look, you need to start further down the list, so use offset() to change where the lookup starts.

```
=MATCH(L$21,$B$23:$B$1000,0)
=MATCH(L$21,OFFSET($B$23:$B$100,L22,0),0)+L22
=MATCH(L$21,OFFSET($B$23:$B$100,L23,0),0)+L23
etc
```

Then to get your list of dates for each food, use index()

```
=INDEX($A$23:$A$34,L22)

sandwich            apple               pancake             eggs
30/01/2017 10:00    30/01/2017 10:00    30/01/2017 10:00    30/01/2017 16:00
#N/A                #N/A                 #N/A               31/01/2017 16:00
#N/A                #N/A                 #N/A               02/02/2017 16:00
```